# How to sort a list of dictionaries in a dictionary and overwrite it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have dictionary which contains list of dictionaries:

```
example = {
"first": [
 {"a": 1, "b": 2},
 {"a": 0, "x": 5}
],
"second": [
{"a": 5, "b": 2},
{"a": 2, "x": 5}
]
}
```

I want to sort lists "first" & "second" based on values of key "a". Desired outcome would be:

```
desired = {
"first": [
 {"a": 0, "x": 5},
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}
],
"second": [
{"a": 2, "x": 5},
{"a": 5, "b": 2}
]
}
```

Now, I dont want to create whole new dictionary. Just update lists "first" & "second" in "example" dict.
What I tried:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for k, v in example.items():
    v = sorted(v, key=itemgetter('a'))
```

That has no effect in my example dictionary. However it works for a single list, e.g.:

```
x = [{"a": 1, "b": 2},
    {"a": 0, "x": 5}
]
z = sorted(x, key = itemgetter('a'))
>>> print(z)
[{'a': 0, 'x': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: Your first example didn't work because `v` has no connection back to the original dictionary; it's just a plain local variable.

Comment: One liner without the need for `itemgetter`. `example = {k: sorted(v, key=lambda x: x['a']) for k, v in example.items()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you assign the sorted list, you are just making the 'label' `v` point to the sorted list, not writing it to the dictionary. See below, that code should do what you want.

```
for k, v in example.items():
    example[k] = sorted(v, key=itemgetter('a'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`sorted` returns a new sorted list. There is a build in `sort` method on list which sort the list in-place.

```
for v in example.values():
    v.sort(key=itemgetter('a'))
```